# openlayers3 validate url data on ol.format.GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, openlayers-3

now i have a layer like this that works properly:

```
stations = new ol.layer.Vector({
        name: 'stations',
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: Routing.generate('getData')
        }),
        style: styleFunction
    });
```

url returns a valid geojson array.

I´d like to check if "url" returns "data" or "null" to show an alert. Now im doing a previous ajax call with the same request to check it.

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('getData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var x in data) {
                if (x == "error") {
                    $("#error").html("<div class='alert alert-danger' style=\"margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 8px; height: 34px;\" role='alert'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span><span class='sr-only'>Error:</span>"+data[x]+"</div>");
                    $("#error").show();
                    map.removeLayer(stations);
                } else {
                    $("#error").hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

can i check this from ol3 directly?

thanks

Comment: If you are already doing a previous ajax call, so just pass your data (geojson) to `ol.source.Vector`. Got it? No reason to a second call.

Comment: yes of course but i´d like to check it on the openlayer´s side. So i dont know how to check if "url parameter" returns data or null.